# Checking a JSON attribute's value then passing only certain objects into $scope?

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a `/xyz/:id` route and controller in Angular, which is set up to work with a `$resource` serving up JSON.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams','Results',
      function($scope, $routeParams, Results) {
          Results.get({ _id: $routeParams.id }, function(result) {
              $scope.result = result;
          });
      }]);
```

The `Results` comes from a model that looks similar to this:

```
resultsSchema = new Schema ({
    _id: Number ,
    name: String,
    ...
    events: [{
        _id: Number,
        type: String,
        ...
    }]
});
```

The `type` in the `events` array is a String and contains a set of values which I'm aware of. Things like `yellowcard`, `goal`, and so on.

I want to be able to say something like this (to get the idea):

```
$scope.goals = result.events 
    where result.events.type == 'goal'
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working. `ng-repeat="event in result.match_events | filter: { type: 'goal'}"`

Comment: Haha it works. I was looking at a page where there were no elements that matched the filter. Checked another one and it's all fine. Thanks